# Conditionally setting "-o pipefail" in /bin/sh

Tags: shell

I have a script that uses the `#!/bin/sh` shebang to be compatible with many flavors. *If* this results in a shell that supports it being used, I'd like to run `set -o pipefail`.

How can I either (a) check if the shell supports `pipefail`, or (b) try to set `pipefail` and "catch"/suppress the error if that command fails?

Comment: Something like `set -o pipefail 2> /dev/null`? If it exists, it's enabled, if it doesn't, the error message is suppressed. You can check the exit status if you want to log something.

Answer (score 1):

Benjamin W.'s response was accurate - you can just suppress the error message with `2>/dev/null` and check the error code:

```
#!/bin/sh

if 
  ! set -o pipefail 2> /dev/null   
then
  : take some action if there is no pipefail option
fi
```

Comment: Good points, both, @JohnKugelman.  I'll make the corrections as noted.  I suppose to avoid the issue with malicious users a cautious script writer could include this statement:  `[ -n "$DEBUG" ] && DEBUG=echo`.

Comment: It's not just "older versions of sh" that might not support `&>` -- it's not supported on modern/recent/actively-maintained implementations like dash or ash either. See also the relevant entry in https://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Comment: As for conditionally logging the arguments passed to `:`, that's something `set -x` or `bash -x yourscript` will provide.

Comment: Thanks @CharlesDuffy, `&>` is now purged from my vocabulary.  Apparently, that syntax is the top offender on the obsolete list you provided.

Answer (score 1):

Mark's answer did not work for me with Dash-0.5.10.2-6. The script exits as soon as the `set -o pipefail` line fails, despite it being 'negated' by `!`.

I managed to make it work by running `set -o pipefail` in a sub-shell:

```
#!/bin/sh

if ! (set -o  pipefail 2>/dev/null); then
    echo "There is no pipefail"
else
    echo "Setting pipefail"
    set -o pipefail
fi

false | true
echo "false | true -> $?"
```

Note that this doesn't actually `set -o pipefail` in the current script if it succeeds, which is why it is executed again in the else branch.

Running it with Dash:

```
$ dash ./pipefail.sh 
There is no pipefail
false | true -> 0
```

Running it with Bash:

```
$ bash ./pipefail.sh 
Setting pipefail
false | true -> 1
```